# Issue with my VB.NET web application authentication

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications, web-config, windows-authentication

I have a windows forms based web application written on VB.NET and currently being used by a large number of users.

I currently am facing an issue where the application is being authenticated with an another user account instead of authenticating with the current user using the application.

I am using User.Identity.Name for user authentication and have only Windows Authentication enabled.

**Other Details**

The application is hosted in IIS on a windows 7 server machine from where it is accessible to everyone.

Strange thing is that the issue occurs only for 2 users and works fine for everyone else. Also it occurs only when using the hosted application(production url).

Also there is no default scenario set such as in case a user is not found, then a default user has to be filled in.

**Observations**

1. On debugging the application using the actual code on their local machines, their
   respective user ids are fetched as expected.
2. Issue occurs in

- Chrome regular mode
- Chrome incognito mode
- Firefox regular mode
  Issue doesnt occur in
- Firefox private mode

So I do not have a clue how to proceed here and what might be the root cause for the issue. Can anyone provide me some ideas to find the root cause of the issue and also a way to resolve it?

**What I have tried:**

I have made sure both Anonymous and Form Based modes of authentication are disabled.
Identity Impersonation is set to False.

I have also made sure there are no credentials set for the website in Credentials Manager.

I have also tried clearing browsing data including cache and other cookies.

Comment: "windows forms based web application" - what does that mean? WinForms (`System.Windows.Forms`) **cannot** be used to make Web Applications. Did you mean to say WebForms (`System.Web`) instead?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you not setting the authentication method etc in your code behind, you'll want to set that in your web.config. Make sure one is not overwriting the other (set in 2 places). Also to get the user name you could also grab it from server variables, see what this returns

```
 string user = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER").ToString();
```